# Show that hypotheses $A\theta_0=c$ and $\theta_0=B\delta_0+e$ are equivalent

Tags: hypothesis-testing, linear, matrix

I am working on a following task. Let $A\theta_0=c$ where $A$ $(q \times d)$ and $c$ $(q \times 1)$ are known with rank $r(A)=q$. Show that the former linear hypothesis is equivalent to $\theta_0=B\delta_0+e$ where $B$ $(d \times (d-q))$, $e$ $(d \times 1)$, and $r(B)=d-q$.

I don't really understand completely how to show this but I have started by figuring out the dimensions for $\theta_0$ in the linear hypothesis which should be $(d\times 1)$ and $\delta_0$ which is $((d-q)\times 1)$. However, the latter results in $\theta_0$ having dimension $(d\times 1)$ in the second hypothesis. Any hints how I should approach this?

Comment: Once you recognize this is a basic linear algebra result to characterize the solutions of an inhomogeneous set of simultaneous linear equations, you should have no trouble deriving or looking up the answer.